# Meaning and usages of "short circuit" as a verb

Tags: meaning, verbs, verb-usage

What is the meaning of "short circuits" as a verb in the following sentence:

> Technology **short circuits** this thinking by making the problems obsolete.

Is this use formal and where it can be used?

Note: [This post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/214066/whats-the-meaning-of-the-expression-short-circuit-in-the-text-bellow) is based on a specific context and is not a general answer.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it means "cuts off", or "removes the need for", i.e. technology means that we don't have to think in such a way as often.

I regard it as rather informal. In polite speech, I would simply opt for the slightly long-winded "removes/reduces the need for".